# jqgrid: MySQL specific problems when sorting a date column

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

After running into this problem a couple of times in the last months (I always kept forgetting what the source of this problem was), I decided to post my question and answer here.

It is about a problem with sortable date columns in your `colModel`; here a simple example:

```
{
    name:'my_date', index:'my_date', width:100, search: false, sort: true,
    sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', 
    formatoptions: {srcformat: 'Y-m-d', newformat: 'd.m.Y'}
}
```

when trying to sort this column by clicking on its title in jqgrid, i kept getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: u.parseDate.call(...).getTime is not a function

I was searching everywhere on the net, and could not find anything. It seemed like getting this error in combination with jqGrid was a very rare case.
I double and triple-checked everything in my jqGrid but there seemed to be no mistake on my part.

**UPDATE**
*since I accepted Oleg's answer, here is what was causing the problem and my workaround:*

After taking a look at the data in the database I saw a lot of "zero dates" in the date column. Older MySQL databases often used this instead of NULL: "0000-00-00" or "0000-00-00 00:00:00".

It turned out that this was causing the problem - jqgrid can't handle these "zero dates". So all i had to do was to manipulate my MySQL resultset:

```
CASE WHEN `my_date` = '0000-00-00' THEN ''
    ELSE `my_date`
END `my_date`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report! The reason of the problem is the following. The internal method `jgrid.parseDate` returns the string `"&#160;"` (see [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.9.2/js/grid.base.js#L775-L777)) in case of the date `0000-00-00`:

```
if (ts.m === 0 && ts.y === 0 && ts.d === 0) {
    return "&#160;";
}
```

On the other side [the code](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.9.2/js/grid.base.js#L1446-L1448)

```
findSortKey = function ($cell) {
    return jgrid.parseDate.call(context, dfmt, $cell).getTime();
};
```

just calls `.getTime()` to the result of `$.jgrid.parseDate`. I committed now [the fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/541aa3dd9e6bbf0ac30d1f59035d4a5b3f81e687) which modifies the above code of `findSortKey` to the following

```
findSortKey = function ($cell) {
    var datetime = jgrid.parseDate.call(context, dfmt, $cell);
    // datetime could be the string "&#160;"
    return datetime instanceof Date ? datetime.getTime() : 0;
};
```

It should fix the problem which you reported. Please try the new sources of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).

Comment: oh nice! then I don't have to take care of this problem by myself when using newer free-jqgrid versions. that's awesome, thank you!

Comment: @low_rents: You are welcome! And thank you once more for reporting of the problem. The more people would report all bugs which he/she found the more clean code we will have as the result.

Comment: no problem. I wasn't sure if this could be called a "bug" or not since "0000-00-00" often is not considered to be a valid date.

Comment: @low_rents: I analysed the code and have found one more place where the same problem could exist. So I modified the code [once more](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/01170d9dbaa7fc50a30c8e23713dcbb0da93151c). If you downloaded the previous version, I would recommend to refresh the sources once more. I hope that it's the final changes of the bug.

Comment: ok, thanks! I haven't got the time to test it right now. I use free-jqgrid in production so I can't change versions very frequently. but i hope i will have the time to upgrade and test it in the following days.

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at the data in the database I saw a lot of "zero dates" in the date column. Older MySQL databases often used this instead of `NULL`: "0000-00-00" or "0000-00-00 00:00:00".

It turned out that this was causing the problem - jqgrid can't handle these "zero dates". So all i had to do was to manipulate my MySQL resultset:

```
CASE WHEN `my_date` = '0000-00-00' THEN ''
    ELSE `my_date`
END `my_date`
```